# My App crashes when I pass a UITableViewCell as AnyObject? to an other function

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, anyobject

I already know the solution for my problem, but I just really don't understand what's going on here. I have a `UITableViewController` that takes the cell in `didSelectRow` and uses it for something in an other function. I pass the cell as `AnyObject?`. Now when I drill down into a detail VC and then back up again, repeat those steps 2 more times, my app crashes.

First I thought it's a problem somewhere else in my app, but then I created a sample project with nothing but those few lines and managed to reproduce the bug. I also already filed a radar, but I don't want to die dump (as you never hear back form those radar guys) ;) Can anybody explain to me what's going on here!

```
final class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        doSomethingWith(sender: cell)
    }

}

extension MasterViewController {
    func doSomethingWith(sender: AnyObject?) {
        // I don't even use that sender!!!
        // If the function would read    doSomethingWith(sender: Any?)     everything would be ok!
    }
}
```

If you want you could download the whole sample at: http://www.georgbachmann.com/demo/CrashTest.zip

I'd really like to know what the swift compiler is doing there!

::EDIT::

I just noted that the crash also depends on `doSomethingWith:` being in an extension!

Comment: Why not pass your datasource and `indexPath` instead of the cell?

Comment: That's not the question ;) In the real app of course I use the object behind a datasource using the IndexPath, but I want to display a popover and therefor need the cell itself. But again, that wasn't the question. The question is what's going on with swift. Why is it causing that crash? Why does AnyObject vs Any make such a difference even if the object isn't even used?!?

Comment: I also know what fixes the crash... I just want to understand it...

Comment: I apologize, guess i misunderstood the question

Comment: What error do you get when it crashes?

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
I also just noted that when cleaning up my sample I did move the `doSomethingWith` function into the main class itself. It also works fine that way... When you move it out into an extension, then the problem occurs. I updated the code above and the sample code

Comment: Why pass the cell if you are not using it? Just pass nil

Comment: This looks like a bug in Swift to me.

Comment: @ohr this is just a sample to demonstrate a bug... i want to know WHY the crash occurs...

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you don't "own" the reusable cells. The `UITableView` owns them. Since you're passing the same cell three times to the function with strong reference (you wrote, you know the solution, so I'm omitting it), you increase the ref count of the cell (in this case to be +3, but it doesn't matter). At some point the `UITableView` decides to release its cells, but your `UIViewController` has a strong reference to them. At this point the app crashes. No bug here - you should never pass objects that you don't own.

Comment: If you have a look at the code above, the cell that is passed into the function is not even used. Still it crashes!. I don't keep a reference what so ever. So there are no retain-counts that could be the problem. There is no reason for the TableView to release my cell. And even if it would do so, it should then create a new one when it's used again. But not just crash ;)
It has something todo with it being passed as AnyObject vs. Any..

Comment: @Georg I'm not going to argue with you. I gave you the correct answer. In your project you print "Why oh why" when the cell is being deallocated. You can read about the memory management in iOS here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html.

Comment: Sure, but just passing an object into a function does not make it be owned. It's not kept inside that function (it's not even used). So there is no ref-count that is increased on that cell. And if my VC would have a strong reference (which it doesn't) then the cell would also not be released.
I guess the whole bug here is a problem caused by the swift compiler and I would like to know what it is. It's no problem if my function lives inside the main class, but having it inside an extension and using AnyObject instead of Any causes the problem.